# ClassNotFoundException using Processing's PApplet with Arduino Tool

Tags: java, eclipse, processing, classnotfoundexception, arduino-ide

I developer a basic [Processing](http://processing.org) PApplet to run as a Tool in the [Arduino IDE](http://arduino.cc/) and that ran fine until Arduino 1.5.8. The problem I have is that in Arduino 1.6.0 some of the code got refactored and this happened on the Arduino side:

> " In order to provide a better command line, IDE has been refactored
>   into app and arduino-core which is the old core In order to avoid
>   conflicts between classes, PApplet was moved from
>   `processing.core.PApplet` to `processing.app.legacy.PApplet` "

This explanation came from one of the Arduino IDE developers. It's worth noting that processing.app.legacy.PApplet is a (very)stripped down version of PApplet, discarding all graphics capabilities which I need.

Initially I was getting this error:

```
Uncaught exception in main method: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: processing/core/PApplet
```

Placing Processing's core.jar in the same location as the eclipse exported tool jar fixed this issues, but let to another:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to use "Import Library" to add processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D to your sketch.
    at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.init(Unknown Source)
```

The part that is confusing is I've used Processing's library source java files instead of the core.jar compiled library to avoid this issue, but it didn't change anything.

I've gone through PApplet's source code and found the graphics/renderer class gets loaded and instantiated at runtime [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java#L1672) like so:

```
Class<?> rendererClass =
        Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(renderer);

      Constructor<?> constructor = rendererClass.getConstructor(new Class[] { });
      PGraphics pg = (PGraphics) constructor.newInstance();
```

and [this](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java#L1712) is where the ClassNotFoundException is caught throwing the Runtime exception:

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
//      if (cnfe.getMessage().indexOf("processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL") != -1) {
//        throw new RuntimeException(openglError +
//                                   " (The library .jar file is missing.)");
//      } else {
      if (external) {
        throw new RuntimeException("You need to use \"Import Library\" " +
                                   "to add " + renderer + " to your sketch.");
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("The " + renderer +
                                   " renderer is not in the class path.");
      }

    }
```

I'm getting more comfortable with java, but I don't have enough experience to figure this one out. It looks like a classpath issue, but I'm not sure why this happens and how I should tell java where to find the classes it needs to load.

Here is the code test I'm using based on the Arduino Tool sample that comes with the IDE. Currently I'm exporting the jar file (not runnable) from eclipse:

```
/*
  Part of the Processing project - http://processing.org

  Copyright (c) 2008 Ben Fry and Casey Reas

  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
  (at your option) any later version.

  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  GNU General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
  Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
*/

package com.transformers.supermangletron;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.app.Editor;
import processing.app.tools.Tool;
//import processing.app.legacy.PApplet;

/**
 * Example Tools menu entry.
 */
public class Mangler implements Tool {
  private Editor editor;

  public void init(Editor editor) {
    this.editor = editor;
  }

  private void setupSketch(){
    int w = 255;
    int h = 255;

//      PApplet ui = new PApplet();
    TestApp ui = new TestApp();

      JFrame window = new JFrame(getMenuTitle());
      window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h+20));

    window.add(ui);
      window.invalidate();
      window.pack();
      window.setVisible(true);
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      ui.init();

    System.out.println("setup complete");
  }

  public String getMenuTitle() {
    return "Mangle Selection";
  }


  public void run() {
      setupSketch();
  }

}
```

and here's the basic test Applet I'm trying to display:

```
package com.transformers.supermangletron;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class TestApp extends PApplet {
    public void setup(){
        size(100,100);
    }
    public void draw(){
        background((1.0f+sin(frameCount * .01f)) * 127);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this ClassNotFoundException with my setup?
Any hints on what I should double check regarding class paths?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this error when you run from eclipse, you have to add the library jars to your classpath. You do this by right-clicking your project, going to properties, then to Java Build Path. Make sure the library jars are listed under the Libraries tab.

If you're getting this error when you run an exported jar, then you need to do one of two things:

Either make sure you export a runnable jar with the library jars embedded inside the main jar. Do this from eclipse by right-clicking the project, going to Export, then choosing "runnable jar" from the list.

Or, make sure you set the classpath as a JVM argument. You do this using the -cp option from the command line.

Comment: Hi Kevin, unfortunately I'm having few limitations in my case. Previously when I was using Processing's core.jar I did make sure the library is added to the Build Path (and listed in the Libraries tab). Now I'm using the library's source code in the same source path as my two test classes. Do I need to do anything extra ? Regarding the runnable jar, this does not apply. I'm building an Arduino Tool which essentially is implementing an interface. This gets called by the Arduino IDE so there is no main()/entry point in a Tool implementation...

Comment: ...Similarly to above, since the Tool is instantiated/created by the Arduino IDE, I don't have any control over the command line arguments (such as -cp) as far as I can tell.  Can you think of other reasons these classes are not found at runtime ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand- what do you mean when you say you're using the library's source code? The basic answer to your question is that you need to either include the library jars inside your main jar, or set them as your classpath as an argument. Which you choose, and how you do it, depends entirely on your setup.

Comment: By using the library's source code I mean I copied [Processing's 1.5.1 core library java source files](https://github.com/processing/processing/tree/processing-1.5.1/core/src/processing) into the src folder of my eclipse project

Comment: After double checking that the core.jar is in the Libraries tab of the project's Build Path settings, I got paranoid that somehow the classes aren't visible, so I've used the uncompiled java classes directly. I'm still getting the ```ClassNotFoundException``` though which I don't really understand. This shouldn't happen if I use the source files right ? These classes would end up being zipped alongside the rest of the code in the exported jar, right ?

Comment: Well, apparently they aren't. Are you sure they're compiling correctly? I really wouldn't use the source like that. Keep the source in its own project, or just use the supplied library jars.

Comment: I wish the library jar would've just worked, but at this point I'm willing to try anyhing. The code compiles correctly (otherwise I wouldn't be able to run the code and see the runtime exceptions). Thanks for the suggestions (+1), will try any others you may have

Comment: I would really recommend **not** including the source like that. Go back to the normal setup of just having the library jars on your classpath. Export the jar. Then open the jar in an archive viewer (like winzip or 7zip), or use the -tf option to see what files are in the jar. Is that class located where it should be?

Comment: Hey Kevin, I may give up on trying to get PApplet with graphics playing nicely in newer versions of Arduino and rewrite it to remove depencies to PApplet.